# Android Studio failed to compile values file

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I get a "Failed to compile values file" error when I build my app in Android Studio. When I trace it back, I find this is the cause: `> Task :app:mergeDebugResources /home/******/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2b32a52804d1f1842c2b39552e0635b5/transformed/material-1.5.0/res/values/values.xml:203:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.`

And when I find the line with the error in the values.xml file, it's this: `<bool name="mtrl_btn_textappearance_all_caps">true</bool>`

I tried "clean project", "rebuild project", "Run with --scan", fixing any warnings, and adjusting the compileAndroidSkd level in gradle.build based on suggested fixes when researching this error, but no suggested solution has solved the error.

I know can't edit values in values.xml file since it's part Android Studio and not my app. So, I am wondering what solutions to this error there might be. In addition, I was wondering for future reference, if you could override values in the values.xml within an app, so not to change original .xml file?

Here is my gradle.build code:

```
Plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.******.******"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When I had the "Failed to compile values file" error it turned out that I had mis-defined a colour as
<color name="delbacktint">red</color>
when it should have been
<color name="delbacktint">@color/red</color>.

I did not receive a complaint from the editor, and F2 did no find anything. I just ended up reviewing each line until that struck me.